# Explain why there's no ordering of the field?

Tags: ordered-fields

> Let $\mathscr{F}=\{0,1\}$ and suppose that addition and multiplication
> are defined on $\mathscr{F}$ *not* in the usual way but by means of
> the "peculiar" addition and multiplication tables below:
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|ccc}+&0&1\\\hline0&0&1\\1&1&0\end{array} \qquad
> \begin{array}{c|cc}\times&0&1\\\hline0&0&0\\1&0&1\end{array}$$
>
> (Note that $1+1=0$.) Show, by considering all possible values for $a$,
> $b$, and $c$ that $\mathscr{F}$ is a field under the "peculiar" rules
> of addition and multiplication given.
>
> Explain why no ordering of the field $\mathscr{F}$ is compatible with its
> arithmetic (i.e. all possible orderings violate one of the axioms of
> order)

I was able to prove that $\mathscr{F}$ is a domain, but how do I prove that it doesn't have an arithmetic compatible order, can you give me some help? thanks.

Comment: Well, there are only two possible orderings in this case: either $0<1$ or $1<0$. So just check that both of them will not make it an ordered field.

Comment: If $0< 1$ then $1+1 < 0 + 1$ so $0< 1$.

Comment: I guess it's over kill to note that if $0$ is the additive identity then $1^2 = 1 > 0$.... which is why I assumed $0< 1$ in my comment above and did not consider $1< 0$.   ... Of course it'd simpler to just stat $0< 1 \iff 0+1 < 1+1 \iff 1< 0$... (For some values of "simple")

Comment: Every ordered field must have characteristic zero. So, $\mathscr{F}$ cannot be an ordered field as it has characteristic two.